# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
cities = ["New York", "Shanghai", "Munich", "Tokyo", "Dubai", "Mexico City", "São Paulo", "Hyderabad"]

for city_m in cities:
    if cities.startswith("M"):
        print("Cities that start with M:", cities)
    else:
        print("No cities start with M.")
```

### print(cities)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      4 
      5 for city_m in cities:
----> 6     if cities.startswith("M"):
      7         print("Cities that start with M:", cities)
      8     else:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'

I'm trying to list cities that start with "m", but I get the error in the title, and I don't understand it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, and I appreciate any feedback on this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the wrong variable in the for loop:

```
for city_m in cities:
    if cities.startswith("M"):
```

it should be:

```
for city_m in cities:
    if city_m.startswith("M"):
```

Although this won't fully solve your problem as you are looping through the entire list, and this will print cities everytime, you should instead add the cities starting with m to a list and then check that list outside of the loop:

```
cities = ["New York", "Shanghai", "Munich", "Tokyo", "Dubai", "Mexico City", "São Paulo", "Hyderabad"]

m_cities = []

for city_m in cities:
    if city_m.startswith("M"):
        m_cities.append(city_m)

if m_cities:
    print("Cities that start with M:", m_cities)
else:
    print("No cities start with M.")

# Prints "Cities that start with M: ['Munich', 'Mexico City']"
```